# jquery - changing bg image of separate div with link

Tags: jquery, background-image, swap

I'm wanting to have the background image of a div change when a link is clicked, but the following isn't working. Also would like it to fade if that's possible...

```
<style type="text/css>
    #banner { background: url(img/img.jpg); }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#change').click(function () {
        $('#banner').css("background-image", "url(img/otherImage.jpg)");
    });
</script>

<div id="banner">
    stuff
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="leftCol">
        <a href="#" id="change">Change</a>
    </div>
    <div id="rightCol">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're binding too early. You need to instruct jQuery to wait until the document is ready before your try to attach any handlers:

```
$(function(){
    $("#change").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#banner").css("background-image", "url('img/otherImage.jpg')");
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ATrF6/1/

Comment: That works perfectly, however, now I realize I need to change the class! I tried this:
`$("#banner").addClass("other");`
but that's not working.

Comment: Depending on the specificity of the css the class you are appending may not do anything.  For instance if you have a class defined as  `.bluebg { background: url(img/blue.jpg); }` it won't change the background of the `#banner` element.  It would need to be defined as `#banner.bluebg {background: url(img/blue.jpg)}`